# Any differential equation has a complete reparametrization

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose that $\dot{ x }= f(x)$ is a differential equation defined on
an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show that the differential equation has a complete reparametrization.

Comment: What do you mean by complete reparametrization?

Comment: Possibly a special case of [“Completing” a vector field on a non-compact manifold M](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378783/completing-a-vector-field-on-a-non-compact-manifold-m?rq=1).

Comment: @CheeHan By complete representation, I mean the solution exists for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I do not understand it. I appreciate it if you explain it in a more simple language @user539887

Comment: You know what is "complete Riemannian metric"?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with that (I do not have any background in differential geometry).

Comment: Perhaps that can be proved in a more straightforward way, without using such a heavy machinery of differential geometry as in the references I have given. But I don't know of any such proof.

Comment: @Artour See Evgeny's comment in [Techniques to prove that solutions of ODE are defined for all time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839993/techniques-to-prove-that-solutions-of-ode-are-defined-for-all-time?noredirect=1#comment5861516_2839993); this is just what you need.